# Error creating Node.js Express App. Cannot find

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

[image: error msg]

Im trying to create a node.js project in WebStorm
Can you tell what am I missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got the solution from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000137190-Create-express-4-15-project-fails-

It works!

1. npm install -g express-generator
2. express <project_name>
3. cd <project_name>, npm install
4. in webstorm, File | open, choose <project_name> folder

Comment: If somebody is having the same issue, this answer is a little bit more understandable.
.....
2. express <project_name>
3. cd <project_name>
4. npm install
....

Comment: Thank you @FureturPhyarell for fixingmy mistake. I copy pasted it so <project_name> went missing.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem!. 
The Old WebStorm show this problem to create version 4.15.0 express-app but it works properly for express version 4.14.1 and less.

Answer (score 3):

Just choose a different Express version in popup (4.14.1, for example). While installing through Webstorm.

Comment: This answer has already been provided, and in more detail, and is currently the top rated answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing required dependencies globally?
It's usually done like this:

```
npm install [dependency_name] -g
```

In your case it might be that express-generator is either not installed globally or not available in PATH.

Comment: Yeah. I installed express-generator globally

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, when you type:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

Use sudo, otherwise it won't work. Like this:

```
(1) sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

Then:

```
(2) express <Your_project_name>
(3) cd <Your_project_name>
(4) npm install
(5) In WebStorm, File --> Open --> <Your_project_name>
```