# Unable to create an Express app in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I tried to create the node application in this directory: **C:\Users\VINOTH RAVI\WebstormProjects** but I'm not able to create the nodejs app.
I enclosed the error.

Can anyone solve this issue?

[image: See here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125932/error-creating-node-js-express-app-cannot-find

Comment: Thanks  it works perfectly.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error creating Node.js Express App. Cannot find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125932/error-creating-node-js-express-app-cannot-find)

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem has already been flagged on IntelliJ's support site.

Here is a link to the answer:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000137190-Create-express-4-15-project-fails-?page=1#community_comment_115000174210

1. npm install -g express-generator
2. `express <project_name>`
3. `cd <project_name>`, `npm install`
4. in webstorm, File | open, choose `<project_name>` folder